# bind mounting and df output

Tags: mount, disk-usage, fstab, bind

I have a partition, **/dev/sdb1**, that gets mounted at **/data**. In /etc/fstab I have:

```
/dev/sdb1           /data           ext4  defaults  1 2
```

After that partition gets mounted, I then have the following bind mounts:

```
/data/backups/f17/opt   /opt            none  rw,bind   0 0
/data/backups/f17/home  /home           none  rw,bind   0 0
/data/var/www/html      /var/www/html/  none  rw,bind   0 0
```

All the mounting is done just fine.

**The problem is that when I run `df`, the only entry I get relating to sdb1 points to "/opt", not "/data".**

e.g.:

```
/dev/sdb1   240233144 196081648 31925236 86% /opt
```

I expect/want `df` to show the original mount point, that is **/data**, instead of **/opt**.  Or at the very least, show *all* the mount points related to sdb1.  If I `umount` the /opt bind mount point, then `df` happily shows /data (even though the other two bind mounts are still mounted, strangely).

There is no difference in behavior if I do the mounting commands in the terminal (vs letting the system do it via `mount -a`, which uses /etc/fstab).

I know I can use something like `findmnt --df` to get a better picture of all mounted filesystems, but I want to use `df` (and I don't want to alias df to anything else).

- Fedora 21
- kernel 3.19.3-200.fc21.x86_64
- df (GNU coreutils) 8.22
- mount from util-linux 2.25.2

thanks.

**UPDATE**

(adding more information)

The file `/proc/mounts` shows all four mount points:

```
/dev/sdb1 /data ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/sdb1 /var/www/html ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/sdb1 /home ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/sdb1 /opt ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
```

Comment: Perhaps it shows the shortest mountpoint? What are the contents of `/proc/mounts` and `/etc/mtab` (if the latter is not a symlink to the latter)?

Comment: `/etc/mtab` is a link to `/proc/self/mounts`.  `/proc/mounts` shows all 4 entries, will add to post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A bind mount is equivalent to the original. There isn't one that's marked as the original and one that's marked as a copy. Bind mounts are like hard links in this respect, not like symbolic links.

Since GNU coreutils 8.21 (if I read the changelog correctly), `df` strives to report each filesystem only once. Older versions included one entry per non-ignored mount point, so a bind mount would result in multiple entries. `df` shows the latest mount point for each filesystem, as far as it can determine. In your case, `df` reports `/opt`, not `/data`, because `/opt` was added last.

Pass the option `-a` to get even recent coreutils to report all entries for each filesystem. This also causes filesystems that would normally be ignored to be listed, if you don't pass a path argument. If you do pass a path argument, I think `df` never reports anything but the latest mount point.

If you don't want to alias `df` to something else, you'll either have to replace `df` by a custom implementation or have to live with `df` reporting something different from what you'd like. If you need the earliest mount point rather than the latest one, a sane solution would be to call `df -a` and retain only the first match for the device that you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks, Gilles, `df -a` will suffice.